# Segfault when allocating large array in Fortran

Tags: memory-management, segmentation-fault, fortran, stack-overflow, gfortran

I have a very simple example of a strange [segfault I am having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458291/problems-compiling-gfortran-in-cygwin-with-large-memory-requirements) and it is as follows:

```
program big_array_segfault

  integer :: nX = 13000
  integer :: nY = 100000
  real(kind = 8), allocatable :: bigarr(:,:)

  allocate(bigarr(nX, nY))

end program big_array_segfault
```

Note that I have 20 GB of RAM to work with and this does not even begin to approach that. Everything I have seen online suggests that this may be a problem with Stack space vs Heap space but I don't know how to control the memory in that way using Fortran.

For what it is worth, the I am compiling with `gfortran -o big_arr.exe test.f90` so there is nothing special going on in the compilation.

Comment: You probably need to increase the stack size.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code

Comment: With allocatables that would be quite strange.

Comment: That alone asks for 10 GB, doesn't any other part of the program use the other 10 GB?

Comment: I tried a few versions of gfortran and stack sizes, and this code ran fine on linux.   It may have something to do with cygwin, but I don't have Windows atm and cannot test. Did you try to use MinGW instead?

Comment: why is this a new question? Couldn't you update the previous one you're referring to?

Comment: I thought about it, but the tags, title and general idea of the last question was quite different than this simplified version about stack/heap, so I made a new one. I think the problem may be Windows 8. I am running it on our cluster (256 GB RAM Linux) and it is working fine. I have a VM but I have access to less RAM but the file needed for this computation is ~100+ GB and the VM is only 250 GB large.

Comment: @Laurbert515 If it is a bug in Cygwin, very little can be done but to download a new version.  The alternative, MinGW, tends to have less bug in my experience, but that was a while ago.  Maybe you can give that a try.

Comment: Could you add the `status=` statement to `allocate`? The resulting error code might give further hints!

Comment: does not segfault for me on 64bin Ubuntu Precise w/ 16gb RAM with stock gfortran. Cygwin / Windows issue?